# Does a verified deployer contract implies that it's child token contract is also verified upon creation?

Tags: contract-deployment, verify, contract-verification

Token address: https://etherscan.io/token/0x12b19d3e2ccc14da04fae33e63652ce469b3f2fd

Contract address: https://etherscan.io/address/0x12b19d3e2ccc14da04fae33e63652ce469b3f2fd

Deployer contract: https://etherscan.io/address/0x94dc1cf66c8fd62ef3bd7da53f47423862839823

So, can we say that the GRID token is verified, simply because it was deployed by another verified token sale contract?

EDIT:
A definite answer has not yet been given in the related earlier asked question.

Comment: Not possible, but exact duplicate, these are even the same addresses !